# Strange call to a member function on a non-object php

Tags: php

So I create a Supermarket class and initiate two objects like this:

```
$items[0] = new Supermarket("Item1", 2.70);
$items[1] = new Supermarket("Item2", 1.0);
```

Then I call the showItem() method on the first object of the array and it works:

```
$items[0]->showItem();
```

But when I try to use a for or a foreach loop through the array to show all the items I get the non-object error. The following won't work either:

```
$i = 0;
$items[i]->showItem();
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Shouldn't that be `$items[$i]`?

Comment: Yes, idea to google this error. But ok, short explanation: your `$items[i]` is not an object since there's no `i`-th element, only `$i`-th

Comment: @AlmaDoMundo, how come you are so smart? I didn't think of Googling it..

Comment: @BenFortune, and the rest of you thanks! Too much coding in C++ for college so I messed it up! :P

Answer (score 1):

You are not using the variable sign `$`

```
$i = 0;
$items[$i]->showItem();
```

Answer (score 1):

change like

```
$i = 0;
$items[i]->showItem();


$i = 0;
$items[$i]->showItem();
```

Answer (score 0):

`$items[$i]` instead of `$items[i]`